# How to show Wikidata sitelink in wikipedia article

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wiki, wikidata

I have a local version of `Wikipedia` and `Wikidata` running. I would like to have an association between an `article` and `wikidata object` in the sidebar like in the standard installation.

But in my version, the field `Wikidata item` is not shown under `Tool` in the sitebar. What should I do in order to have that?

Edit:

Added the LocalSetting part. I can also see the toolbox and Addlink, just the wikidata link is not there

```
# Enabled extensions. Most of the extensions are enabled by adding
# wfLoadExtensions('ExtensionName');
# to LocalSettings.php. Check specific extension documentation for more details.
# The following extensions were automatically enabled:
wfLoadExtension( 'Babel' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Cite' );
wfLoadExtension( 'CiteThisPage' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ConfirmEdit' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Gadgets' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ImageMap' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Interwiki' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Nuke' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ParserFunctions' );
require_once "$IP/extensions/PdfExport/PdfExport.php";
wfLoadExtension( 'Poem' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Renameuser' );
wfLoadExtension( 'UniversalLanguageSelector' );
require_once "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/Wikibase.php";
wfLoadExtension( 'WikibaseQuality' );
wfLoadExtension( 'WikibaseQualityConstraints' );
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );
#wfLoadExtension( 'Mpdf' );
wfLoadExtension( 'TextExtracts' );
#require_once("$IP/extensions/PageSummariesAPI/PageSummariesAPI.php");
# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.

#Configuration to enable Wikibase client and Repo

$wgEnableWikibaseRepo = true;
$wgEnableWikibaseClient = true;
require_once "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/repo/Wikibase.php";
require_once "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/repo/ExampleSettings.php";
require_once "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/client/WikibaseClient.php";
require_once "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/client/ExampleSettings.php";
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is provided by the [Wikibase Client MediaWiki extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wikibase_Client). You can see that it is added [in the extension's source code](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Wikibase/blob/master/client/ClientHooks.php#L117), where it is added through `onBaseTemplateToolbox`. According to [MediaWiki's documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/BaseTemplateToolbox), *onBaseTemplateToolbox* is "Called by BaseTemplate when building the toolbox array and returning it for the skin to output."

The [Wikibase Client extension's documentation only mentions the *other projects sidebar*](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Installation/Advanced_configuration#Features_&_Usage) and I could find no information whether the Wikidata item link is created by default.

From the [English Wikipedia's sidebar configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Sidebar) you can see that the link resides in the *TOOLBOX* section, which you will need to add to your sidebar if it is not already there.

Comment: Sorry, I think you are right, but I do not understand clearly about the last step. Does it mean I should put the config somethingn like this: $wgWBClientSettings['TOOLBAR'] => array( 'wikidata' );

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. You need to make sure that your *MediaWiki:Sidebar* has a `TOOLBOX` section. Otherwise, there obviously will be no *Tools* section in the sidebar.

Comment: I added some more information I found with regard to how the link ends up in the toolbox. I assume that it works right out-of-the-box if you add the Wikibase Client extension to your MediaWiki instance. If it doesn't, you should ensure that the onBaseTemplateToolbox hook of the Wikibase Client extension is registered.

Comment: I do have an toolbox section, but the wikidata link is missing from there.Might be my mistake but I think the link should be there if the wikidata object itself has the link to an article

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your LocalSettings.php, where you include the WikibaseClient extension? Do you see the *Add Links* link as described [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Installation#Wikibase_Client)?

Comment: I edited my question to include the information. I can see the toolbox and the addlink

Comment: Have you confirmed that the hook is active/configured?